# What is the difference between {% load staticfiles %} and {% load static %}

Tags: django, django-templates

The most important part of the question is in the topic.

I am wondering what tag is best for which case. Moreover... I found code, that also use `settings.STATIC_URL` included by `{{STATIC_URL}}` in the templates.

I am a little confused.

Comment: I just use STATIC_URL for everything and it seems to work fine for me

Comment: @Maximas It does work, but I guess its not best practice

Comment: None of these answers are good. This is a [more recent and complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424007/1577947).

Answer (score 62):

[The built-in `static` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#static) "link[s] to static files that are saved in `STATIC_ROOT`".

[The `staticfiles` contrib app's `static` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) "uses the configured `STATICFILES_STORAGE` storage to create the full URL for the given relative path", which is "especially useful when using a non-local storage backend to deploy files".

The built-in `static` template tag's documentation (linked to above) has a note that says to use the `staticfiles` contrib app's `static` template tag "if you have an advanced use case such as using a cloud service to serve static files", and it gives this example of doing so:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" alt="Hi!" />
```

You could use `{% load staticfiles %}` rather than `{% load static from staticfiles %}` if you want, but the latter is more explicit.

Comment: [Django V1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#static) now recommends just `{% load static %}`. "In older versions, you had to use `{% load static from staticfiles %}` in your template to serve files from the storage defined in STATICFILES_STORAGE. This is no longer required."

Comment: Since 2016 we only need to use `{% load static %}`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what the difference is supposed to be, but I found a use case difference (using django 1.9.1 running via apache, wsgi on Python 3.4). In my app, I have some images in `ImageFields` in the database. If I use code like this in my template:

```
<a href="object-{{object.id}}"><img src="{% static object.image %}" height="200px"></a>
```

then, if I use `{% load static %}`, django throws a `TypeError` (`Cannot mix str and non-str arguments`). This is presumably because the `object.image` is not a string, it's an `ImageField`, that gets converted to a string at some later stage. However, if one uses `{% load staticfiles %}` no such error occurs.

Unfortunately, I discovered this difference after spending hours trying to debug the problem. I managed to find a workaround for when using the first option, namely to add a string-converter method to the object like this:

```
#image string
def image_str(self):
    return str(self.image)
```

Hope this knowledge will be of use to someone.

Answer (score 5):

Django documentation prefers now `{% load static %}`.

`{% load staticfiles %}` works but I think it is deprecated.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static), where there is a nice explanation of it.
Actually the `{% static %}` template tag know the location of [STATICFILE_STORAGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_STORAGE)

As docs say :

> ```
>  {% load static from staticfiles %} <img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg"
>  %}" alt="Hi!" /> The previous example is equal to calling the url method of an instance of STATICFILES_STORAGE with "images/hi.jpg".
> ```
>
> This is especially useful when using a non-local storage backend to
>   deploy files as documented in Serving static files from a cloud
>   service or CDN.
>
> If you’d like to retrieve a static URL without displaying it, you can
>   use a slightly different call:
>
> ```
> {% load static from staticfiles %}
> {% static "images/hi.jpg" as myphoto %}
> <img src="{{ myphoto }}" alt="Hi!" />
> ```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: I still don't know when should I use `{% load static %}`, `{% load staticfiles %}`, `{{STATIC_URL}}`... and know I don't know what is the difference between `{% load static %}` and `{% load static from staticfiles %}`

Comment: simply copying a bunch of lines from the doc doesn't really help

Answer (score 1):

`{% load staticfiles %}` is very helpful when you are using different storages like S3, then it will convert into the S3 URLs