# Django Invalid block tag: 'static'

Tags: python, django

I have this in the `<head>` of my base.html.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "myStyleSheet.css" %}">
```

and I get error **Invalid block tag: 'static'**

Within INSTALLED_APPS I've included

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

and I've included within settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static/")
```

Why do I get the load error?

Comment: Try using single-quotes around `myStyleSheet.css` instead of double-quotes.

Comment: The error is on the "{% static " part of the html <link>

Comment: I've tried single quotes - no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the actual problem here, I'm very sorry to say, was that within my app.yaml file I had specified a different directory for the static files and it seemed to be overriding everything else.  Once removed, all sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `django.core.context_processors.static` context processor in your `TEMPLATE` settings? Here's a sample:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

You can add it there or use `{ %load static %}` in your template.

Comment: I've just tried adding it (to settings.py) but that hasn't made any difference

Comment: You don't need to add the entire block, just find the `TEMPLATES` section, find the `context_processors` part and add that one to the last.

Comment: I've used the following : TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
) which is now giving me a different error, namely: Module "django.core.context_processors" does not define a "static" callable request processor

Comment: What version of Django do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Use `{% load static %}` or `{% load static from staticfiles %}`

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/27516199/263989

Comment: using either I get the message: 'static' is not a valid tag library: Template library static not found, tried django.templatetags.static,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.static

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything is fine. Check if `static` word is written using only English letters, it may be because of this.

Comment: all in English letters

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
href="{% static "myStyleSheet.css" %}"
```

to

```
href="{% static 'myStyleSheet.css' %}"
```

Single quotes for `myStyleSheet.css`

Answer (score 0):

Many answers are here but try this too. I'm going to describe everything. forget and clear anything added before and just follow these hints

1- in your **settings.py** and `INSTALLED_APPS` you should have
`'django.contrib.staticfiles',`

and also `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. by default it's exists in the end of your file but check again yourself

---

2- in **settings.py** your `TEMPLATES` should be like as follow

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Do not try to add this again !** just check for mistakes

---

3- `static` folder must be in the application directory not your main directory of project

```
project
    -application
        -migrations
        -static
        -templates
```

---

4- in `static` folder create sub directories for your files for example

```
project
    -application
        -static
            -css
            -js
            -img
            -....
            -....
```

and put your files to specific folder

---

5- now in your HTML file add `{% load staticfiles %}` first of file and everywhere you need a *static file* try to add that like as follow

```
<link href="{% static "css/myStyleSheet.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<link rel="icon" href="{% static "img/favicon.png" %}">
```

---

If you follow these hints, everything should be OK. test and report again