# Django app not updating static files in browser

Tags: python, django, browser, django-autocomplete-light

The static files from third-party apps are not being updated in my Django site when it is served up in a browser with `runserver`.

Here is my file structure (with many more static files):

```
- mysite
  - mysite
    - settings.py
    - wsgi.py
    . . .
  - myapp
    - templates
      - base.html
      - myapp.html
    - models.py
    - forms.py
    . . . 
  - static
    - MyApp
      - mystyle.css
    - autocomplete-light
      - select2.css
```

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>
    {% block title %}Portal{% endblock title %}
  </title>
  {% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/mystyle.css' %}?{% now "U" %}"/>
  {% endblock stylesheets %}
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
</body>
<footer>
  {% block footer %}
  {% endblock footer %}
</footer>
</html>
```

myapp.html:

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}My App{% endblock title %}
{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock stylesheets %}
{% block content %}
  {% crispy formset helper %}
{% endblock content %}
{% block footer %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}?{% now "U" %}"></script>
{{ formset.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py (relevant piece):

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/username/mysite/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I used `python manage.py collectstatic` to collect the static files for my app and the third party app (`django-autocomplete-light`) into the `STATIC_ROOT`. They exist in the STATIC_ROOT. I then served up my site with `runserver`. The static files are loaded with the site and their paths match back to the `STATIC_ROOT`. When I edit the static files (i.e. `select2.css` for the autocomplete app), the changes show up in `STATIC_ROOT`. However, they do not show up in the browser.

I have tried clearing my cache, serving the site in various browsers, killing/restarting runserver, killing/restarting my text editor, and rerunning `collectstatic`. None of these attempts have worked - the static files simply will not update when the site is loaded.

How do I get the static files to update in the browser? I think I might be either missing a setting in `settings.py`, or it may be an issue with `{{ formset.media }}`. I am at a loss, though.

Comment: can you look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial06/

Comment: i have read that, but I don't see anything amiss with how I have things set up. what in particular are you thinking of?

Comment: Maybe need restart and clear all cache, maybe your browser return a cache_file(delete your browser history)

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, i've taken all of those steps already. this is not a browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remember add `STATICFILES_DIRS`, Django need the url to the staticfiles:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    '/var/www/static/', # If you have more staticfiles this will be the order
)
```

and also take a look to this [What is the difference between {% load staticfiles %} and {% load static %}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238496/what-is-the-difference-between-load-staticfiles-and-load-static)